# AWS EC2 Install Chrome as user data

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2

I am trying to automate installation of Chrome along with few other other tasks using PowerShell in User data. However installation of Chrome fails, because it needs PowerShell in elevated mode.

Following is the snippet of my code:

```
<powershell>
#Change TimeZone
C:\Windows\System32\tzutil /s "AUS Eastern Standard Time"

#Install Chrome 
$Path = $env:TEMP;
$Installer = "chrome_installer.exe";
Invoke-WebRequest "http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe" -OutFile     $Path\$Installer; 
Start-Process -FilePath $Path\$Installer -ArgumentList "/silent /install" -Verb RunAs -Wait;
Remove-Item $Path\$Installer

#Set Chrome as default browser
$chromePath = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Google\Chrome\Application\" 
$chromeApp = "chrome.exe"
$chromeCommandArgs = "--make-default-browser"
& "$chromePath$chromeApp" $chromeCommandArgs
</powershell>
```

Can someone please advise, how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run powershell as administrator. That's how it is . Or if you have a user who is a member of admin group. Run with that user.

Comment: Hi @RanadipDutta, I want to run this script using User Data in EC2 instance. Can you tell me, how can I run the script as Administrator, via user data?

Comment: Make a user a member of admin group in that EC2 system. Open Powershell->> it will actually open with admin rights. So your script will run as admin. Thats what i believe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix the script by adding "Set-Location "C:\Windows\system32" as first line. So my script looks like below:

```
<powershell>
Set-Location "C:\Windows\system32"

#Change TimeZone
C:\Windows\System32\tzutil /s "AUS Eastern Standard Time"

#Install Chrome 
$Path = $env:TEMP;
$Installer = "chrome_installer.exe";
Invoke-WebRequest "http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe" -OutFile     $Path\$Installer; 
Start-Process -FilePath $Path\$Installer -ArgumentList "/silent /install" -Verb RunAs -Wait;
Remove-Item $Path\$Installer

#Set Chrome as default browser
$chromePath = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Google\Chrome\Application\" 
$chromeApp = "chrome.exe"
$chromeCommandArgs = "--make-default-browser"
& "$chromePath$chromeApp" $chromeCommandArgs
</powershell>
```